# How can I programmatically inspect an ActiveXObject at runtime, using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, com, activex, runtime, inspect

I am looking to create a Javascript library for ActiveX objects, enabling chainability.

For example, I am looking to replace this:

```
var dbEngine=new ActiveXObject('DAO.DBEngine.36');
var dbs=dbEngine.OpenDatabase('D:\\Todo.mdb');
var rs=dbs.OpenRecordset('SELECT * FROM ListItems');
```

with something like this (a la jQuery):

```
var rs=AX('DAO.DBEngine.36')
    .OpenDatabase('D:\\Todo.mdb')
    .OpenRecordset('SELECT * FROM ListItems');
```

I know I can do this:

```
var rs=new ActiveXObject('DAO.DBEngine.36')
    .OpenDatabase('D:\\Todo.mdb')
    .OpenRecordset('SELECT * FROM ListItems');
```

but I have no way of accessing the Database object from the Recordset object.

In order to do this, the AX function should create the DBEngine object internally and inspect its members/properties, then expose corresponding methods on the the returned object.

If the member/property returns an object, that object itself will be returned wrapped in the AX function.

Comment: Pretty sure the JScript engine doesn't allow it. AFAIK, IDispatchEx (used by DOM objects in IE) enables some limited enumeration of methods and properties, but unless all objects diligently expose this interface you're stuck. And yes, this is very unfortunate.

Comment: There's always brute force ;-)

Comment: You cannot call anything in an AX object unless it's exposed by IDispatch.

But the original question is quite unclear: What exactly are you trying to do?  You can use the foreach mechanism in JavaScript to enumerate the exposed members of an object.

Comment: @EricLaw: In my experience, this does not work for objects that implement only IDispatch; IDispatchEx is required for enumeration. Has this changed? @jeffamaphone: an API that encourages making method calls on the return value of previous method calls: `$func().func2().func3()` etc. jQuery is probably a familiar example of such a library... And no, i don't know what ZevSplitz is trying to do or why chainability has any connection to programmatically inspecting objects.

Comment: @EricLaw: JScript doesn't support for..each.

Comment: @ZevSpitz: Oops. :-) I meant for...in, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only objects that implement IDispatchEx can be inspected at runtime.  MSDN specifically lists the differences between IDispatch and [IDispatchEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sky96ah7(VS.85).aspx):

> IDispatchEx was developed to provide
>   all the services of IDispatch as well
>   as some extensions that are
>   appropriate for more dynamic
>   late-bound languages such as scripting
>   languages. The additional features of
>   IDispatchEx beyond those provided by
>   IDispatch are:
>
> Add new members to an object
>   ("expando").
>
> Delete members of an object.
>
> Case-sensitive dispatch operations.
>
> Search for member with implicit
>   name.
>
> **Enumerate DISPIDs of an object**.
>
> Map from DISPID to element name.
>
> Obtain properties of object
>   members.
>
> Method invocation with this
>   pointer.
>
> Allow browsers that support the
>   concept of name spaces to obtain the
>   name space parent of an object.

I've made bold the relevant issue.

As Eric points out in the comments, you can use enumerate the members of the objects using foreach (or for...in perhaps?), but I'm not sure, from the question, what you specifically want to do.

Since not all ActiveX controls will implement IDispatchEx (or may not implement all methods of IDispatchEx properly or completely), are there specific controls you're looking to play with?

More details will lead to better answers.